# Android libraries: versions conflict issue

Tags: android

I've the below dependence in my Android app `build.gradle`

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

but getting an error about versions compatibility, as shown below, what is the one to be changed here, i could not figure it out :(

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem what i did was compile the higher version of libraries ,which were creating this error,in app:gradle only.
for example in your case

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
```

Add this in app:gradle.
There may be more like this mediarouter libraries if it still give error add them jst like this(making them higher version).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find out where's what consists of a conflicting version of the library. The easiest way to do so is to:

1. Open `Terminal` pane in your Android Studio.
2. Type in: `./gradlew androidDependencies`
3. Find the row that represents the ENCLOSING library consisting of a conflict.

Then just use `exclude` statement for the conflicting library, like so:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'    
})
```

(the example assuming `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2` was the ENCLOSING library, and `com.android.support:support-annotations` being the conflict)

Comment: Thanks, I run the command, but could not know how to figure out the conflict. the accepted answer solved it smoothly for me.

Comment: It actually only hid the issue, didn't really solve it. If two libraries have the same dependency (library) with different versions you have a conflict. You honestly only had to look at the dependency tree and find the row with `mediarouter`. But nvm, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the dependency tree is very long, and really could not get it easy, my duty is over, i'll check it tomorrow, if worked, will accept your answer instead of the other, nice day to you too :)

Comment: you can also dump the whole tree in the file so it's a bit easier to process `./gradlew androidDependecies > tree.txt`

Comment: I found it in 3 libraries: `'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'` and `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0` and `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1` so, i used the exclusion three times like: `androidTestCompile('xxx', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'mediarouter-v7'
    })` and ended up having 3 errors at sync time like `Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (24.0.0) and test app (25.0.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.`

Comment: 1. Find the library that consists of the `mediarouter` with version `24.0.0`. Exclude `mediarouter` from this particular library. 2. Maybe I wasn't clear enough with the way you have to form your `exclude` statement. The one I included was just an example. And it was excluding `support-annotations` from dependency used for ui tests (that's why there is `androidTestCompile`). For your case change `androidTestCompile` to just the `compile`.

Comment: It worked fine, but what does EXCLUDE means here, if I understood correctly, it completely ignore the consideration of the library `mediarouter` as I still see it in the  `./gradlew androidDependecies > tree.txt` with the wrong version, but what if I really need to use this library, does not this EXCLUSION cause an error for the execution?